# TabbarActivity fragment not called to onActivityResult

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-fragments, android-tabactivity

im using tabbaractivity and one of the tabs contains listView
i want to update the listView every time that i adding object.
to add object i do it from new activity
what i wants is when this activity will close the listView will update by using
adapter.notifydatachanged

in my activity that contains the tabs

```
   if (id == R.id.addButton) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(rootViewTabBarActivity.this, addPictureActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent,101);
        return true;
    }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

in the fragment (one of the tabs)

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if ((requestCode == 101) && (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK))
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and the activity that create the object and save him to database

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAM_REQUEST) {
        Bitmap btmp = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
        takenPhoto.setImageBitmap(btmp);
    }
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> fragment not called to onActivityResult

You miss passing the data from Activity to fragment
In Activity, your code should be like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            YourFragment fragment = getFragment();
            if (fragment != null) {
                // Pass data to Fragment
                fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }

    }

public YourFragment getFragment() {
        // You can find your fragment (by tag/ by id) here depends on your layout
    }
```

Comment: im using TabActivity and from action bar i open new activity to add new the TabActivity create the fargment            @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    MyAreaView myArea = new MyAreaView();
                    return myArea;
                case 1:
                    SearchView search = new SearchView();
                    return search;
            }
            return null;
        }

Comment: im using tabactivity and from the action bar im openning new activity to add object when the new activity closed i want that one fragment active onResume or onActivityResulte to do update to listView from TabActivity your fragment create in function SectionsPagerAdapter....somthing like that